# Issue with HighChart's StockChart. Getting highcharts is not a function

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, highcharts

So I have two doubts:

Q1:

I am unable to understand the difference between the two ways to initialize a High Chart:

1st way:

```
var lineChart = new Highcharts.Chart(
  {
    chart: {
        alignTicks: true,
        type : 'StockChart',
        renderTo : 'container',
...
```

2nd way:

```
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
        chart: {
            alignTicks: true,
            type : 'StockChart',
            renderTo : 'container',
...
```

Q2:

When Using the 2nd way on http://jsfiddle.net/ezk2mg72/ I am able to get desired result but when trying in local I am getting following exception:

```
**Uncaught TypeError: $(...).highcharts is not a function**
```

PS: the order of js files is correct as per different posts of stackoverflow suggested:

```
(I have scripts in local)
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/highstock.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/exporting.js"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ezk2mg72/

Comment: I am not sure what `Highcharts_latest.js` is. I would remove that.

Comment: Sorry ! That was for some other module.

Comment: If you remove that does it work?

Comment: Yes ! It does work :D Thanks a lot !! But The issue is ... I need that as well ! Don't know how to proceed with that.

Comment: What is `highcharts_latest.js` doing for you that `highstock.js` isnt?

Comment: I am using heatmap.js on the same page and when I remove highcharts_latest.js I am getting following exception: Uncaught TypeError: HighchartsAdapter.addAnimSetter is not a function

Comment: Use the correct method. Via the API you need to use the `heatmap.js` module (and possibly `data.js` module): <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/heatmap.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/data.js"></script>

Comment: @wergeld Thanks for your help ! The issue was with inconsistent version on js files in my local project. By using the latest (using only highstock as it contains almost everything which highcharts have) worked perfectly.

Answer (score -2):

Loot at the error number before this error Uncaught TypeError and click to the link on your console to view the problem detail :

> Uncaught Error: Highcharts error #16: www.highcharts.com/errors/16

And Good luck !